# URL rewriting - two custom classes CategoryRewriteRule for two organizations

Tags: intershop

Structurally there is **one project** with **two organizations**. Each organization "resides" in own cartridges.

There are two custom classes which extends `CategoryRewriteRule` (which extends superclass `BaseRewriteRule` - rule that which provides information as site, server group, locale, application URL identifier and currency) for each organization (apps) and both are added to extensions (`RewriteRule.create`).

Also in `domainsplittings.xml` are defined domains which separates sites/apps of both organizations.

---

When category page is viewed on any site/app (organization) both rules are executed.

Is there a way i can prevent this and how?

Or i will need to use only one rule class with analyzing site/app two create different URL patterns and move that class to some common cartridge for both organizations?